# Can math be used in parse_ini_file configuration file?

Tags: php, parsing

Can math be used in a parse_ini_file configuration file?  If not, is there a recommended workaround?

```
$ini = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
```

config.ini

```
MAX_FILE_SIZE  =   100*pow(2,20)   ;100 MB
```

Comment: Why do not you try it? Anyway, i tried it and no. It will gives you syntax error.

Comment: @lolka_bolka.  I did try it, and only afterwards posted this question.  Didn't know if there was another way to include math in the config file.

Comment: See my answer... There is an option `scanner_mode` for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this!

```
$a = parse_ini_file('a.ini', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

From PHP doc:

```
If INI_SCANNER_RAW is supplied, then option values will not be parsed.
```

So, you can collect the whole array, and then create a foreach loop, and use `eval` on the values.

Check my code: (**knowing bug** that not remove the eval_next_line, but now i got to go. Monday i will fix that. Till that, you can fix also if you have time for it. Anyway, the round is happens. Yes, the error is that, i have the eval_next_line key twice, so i need to fix that. Anyway, monday.)

```
define('EVAL_NEXT_LINE', 'eval_next_line');

//Default removing the eval_next_lines
$removeEvals = true;
$options = parse_ini_file('a.ini', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
if (array_key_exists("remove_evals", $options)) {
    if (empty($options['remove_evals']) || strtolower($options['remove_evals']) == 'no') {
        $removeEvals = false;
    }
}

$i = 0;
$evalNextLine = false;
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    if ($evalNextLine === true) {
        $options[$key] = eval("return " . $value .";");
        $evalNextLine = false;
    }
    if ($key == EVAL_NEXT_LINE && ($value || strtolower($options[EVAL_NEXT_LINE] = 'yes'))) {
        $evalNextLine = true;
        if ($removeEvals) {
            unset($options[$i]);
            //$i--;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

var_dump($options);
```

My `a.ini` is:

```
[Parse options]
remove_evals = 1;


[Somethings]
eval_next_line = true;
myvar = round(2.5);

abc = xyz;

eval_next_line = true;
myvar2 = 100*pow(2,20);

[Somthing others]
anythig = true;
```

Comment: Nice workaround, however, I will probably just do the math manually, and comment the equations I used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, or recommended. However, one thing you can do which is sort of a work-around, but unfortunately removes the actual value of using a config file in the first place is use constants:

```
define( 'MAX_FILE_SIZE' , 100*pow(2,20) );
```

Then use the constant in the ini file itself.

Comment: Thanks, but don't really wish to do this for the reasons you stated.  Guess I just include the math as a comment, and break out my handy calculator.

Answer (score 0):

The math you've given in your ini file will throw an error because you're using reserved characters (`?{}|&~![()^"`). A workaround, albeit 'risky' (because the use of `eval()`), would be;

#### config.ini

```
MAX_FILE_SIZE  = 100*2;
MAX_FILE_SIZE_POW = 20;
```

#### PHP Script

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
eval('$base = '. $ini['MAX_FILE_SIZE'] .';');
eval('$ini["MAX_FILE_SIZE"] = '.  bcpow( $base, $ini['MAX_FILE_SIZE_POW'], 2) .';');
echo sprintf("%f", $ini['MAX_FILE_SIZE']);
```

**Cons**

- Using `eval()`
- You need two separate configurations

We are using `sprintf` so we have control over the output. Without it we'd get `1.048576E+46`.